# How to move tasks from one User Story to another

Tags: tfs

In TFS, is it possible to drag&drop a task from one User Story to another?

You can do it in the web tree view.
the only way is in Excel.   Is that really the case?

You used to be able to do this in Visual Studio

Comment: What **version** of TFS? It's possible in modern versions.

Comment: latest version on prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to move tasks from one User Story to another

It is easy to move tasks from one User Story to another User Story. You just drag the task from one User Story to another.

If you want do this in Visual Studio, first you should change the type of opening work item:

In the Visual Studio, Tools->Options->Work Items->General->Open work item in, select **Visual Studio (compatibility mode)**:

[image]

Then open a new Query to list the work item you want to modify, like, the task `TestA1`, which in the User Story 302. And I want move it User Story 304:

[image]

Open it, click the ALL LINKS, and edit the link to the User Story 304:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure this can be done in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @ArtGhangsta, Yes. I only installed the VS2017 on my PC.